# gradually decrease variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and I am struggling with this idea I want to implement.

The thing I am trying to accomplish is that you choose a amount of people on a slider from 100 to 1000 people. And beginning from 100 each person pays 10 euro and this gradually decreases(becomes cheaper) to 5 euro per person for 1000 people.

My best attempt was to do it in chunks, but this was a bad idea. Since `199 x 10 = 1990` and `200 x 9 = 1800`.

my attempt:

```
var people = $1;
var result = 0;

if ( people > 100 && people <= 200 )
result = people * 10;
if ( people > 200 && people <= 300)
result = result + people * 9;

return result;
```

So the question is how can I gradually decrease the cost per person?
Thanks in advance!

I changed the code to:

```
var people = $1;
var result = 0;
var domain = (200 - 100) / (16.75 - 14.75);
var discount = (people - 100) / domain;
var domain2 = (300 - 200) / (14.75 - 13.75);
var discount2 = (people - 200) / domain2;
var domain3 = (400 - 300) / (13.75 - 12.90);
var discount3 = (people - 300) / domain3;

if ( people > 100 && people <=200)
result = (people * (16.75 - discount));
if ( people > 200 && people <=300)
result = (people * (14.75 - discount2));
if ( people > 300 && people <=400)
result = (people * (13.75 - discount3));
if ( people > 400)
result = (people * 12.90);

return result;
```

Probably not the best way to do it, or rather a stupid way, but it works.
Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Explain further. Are you looking for help writing JS code for this, or are you looking for help with the maths involved in how much the price should be, or are you looking for help with both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like this is a mathematical problem and not a coding one.
Let
`n = number of total people`
 `x = number of people selected in the slider`,
 `maxPrice = price when x = 0` 
`minPrice = price when x = n`

You need to find an `f(x)` which has these properties:

- f(0) = maxPrice
- f(n) = minPrice

My naive approach would be using a linear function `f(x) = mx + q` 
You can find the slope of the line `m` using `(minPrice - maxPrice)/n` and the `q` is the value when `f(0)`, which must be `maxPrice`.
So you end up with this formula:

```
f(x) = ((minPrice - maxPrice)/n)*x + maxPrice
```

Which returns values in the interval `[maxPrice, minPrice]` for all  `0 <= x <= n` in a linear way.

Comment: This clarifies the maths a lot! its actually basic linear algebra. Thanks a lot for the great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Some good values for your problem:
coefficient: -0.00555556
intercept: 10.55555556

you can then calculate your price like this: num_people * coefficient + intercept

I assumed that the association between number of people and price is linear.
If this is not the case you would need to work with a non-linear hypothesis, but I am guessing that the function described above will do the job in this case (?)

If you are interested in this stuff I can recommend some reading up on linear algebra.

some very simple example code in python for calculating these numbers with linear regression (python, because it makes the code very simple thanks to the fantastic library support):

```
from sklearn import linear_model
x = [[100], [1000]]
y = [[10], [5]]
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x, y)
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_)
```

There are also some websites that you can use to calculate your coefficient and intercept with linear regression. 
Since I don't think you will need to implement linear regression for your specific problem but just need the values.

Try https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/linear-regression-calculator.php for example.

Now, you will find tons of resources online if you are interested in the nitty gritty details of linear regression. I can strongly recommend the  machine learning course on coursera - the first week is all about linear regression, going into a lot of detail on how the math behind the algorithm works: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this actually is nice and easy to implement. I use it as `result = (people * coefficient + intercept) * people;` But can i ask how you calculated those numbers, since the numbers i give in the example are not the final numbers i will use.

Comment: I used a linear regression model to calculate the numbers (there is a few other mathematical ways of computing the numbers but I went for the simplest solution I could come up with)
The general hypothesis for one feature/univariate (your feature is the number of people) is as follows:
f(x) = coef * x  + intercept
the result is your "label", in your case the price
You can use gradient descent to come up with the "best" values for the coefficient and intercept value - I will update my answer with some example code.
Glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use set values for your "chunks" as shown below:

```
var people = <<<input value>>>;
var result = 0;

if ( people > 100 && people < 200 ) {
    result = 10;
} else if ( people >= 200 && people < 300) {
    result = 9.44;
} else if ( people >= 300 && people < 400) {
    result = 8.88;
} else if...

return result;
```

Also changed your logic a wee bit (else ifs, greater thans etc.)

Comment: thanks a lot!, but so this is the problem, i was doing it this way. But is there a way to do it gradually ? Like with a function.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for here is a function `y=f(x)` which maps from the domain `X` of positive integers between 100 and 1000 to the co-domain `Y` of positive float from 5 to 10. You defined that this function must pair 1000 with 5 and 100 with 10; now you have to decide how it changes in all the between area.

That function can be linear or have any shape you prefer.

I made a desmos example with a linear function, you can have fun with any other function you like: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8iss1umrhn

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the right formula, writing chaining if else most of the times means that your logic is wrong.

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hjbjesg0/1/) of how your code might look like:

```
function getTotalPrice(people) {
  var minPeople = 100;
  var maxPeople = 1000;
  var minPrice = 5;
  var maxPrice = 10;
  // the below calculations are based on the speculations you described in the question
  var domain = (maxPeople - minPeople) / (maxPrice - minPrice);
  var discount = (people - minPeople) / domain;

  return '$ ' + (people * (maxPrice - discount)).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i will have a look.